# If the AM and GM between two numbers are in the ratio $m:n$, then what is the ratio between the two numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, ratio, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If the AM and GM between two numbers are in the ratio $m:n$,
then what is the ratio between the two numbers?

I have tried many approach like
Let's two number be $a$ and $b$
Then their AM will be $\frac{a+b}{2}$
and their GM will be $(ab)^{1/2}$.
But putting these values and after solving equation become much complex.

Please tell me how to solve further.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be positives and $a=bx$.

Thus, $$\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}}{\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{m}{n}$$ or
$$x+1=\frac{2m\sqrt{x}}{n}.$$
Now, solve this quadratic equation.

Can you end it now?

I got that the needed ratio it's
$$\left(\frac{m}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{n^2}-1}\right)^2$$ or
$$\left(\frac{m}{n}-\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{n^2}-1}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $ab>0$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{a+b}{2\sqrt{ab}} & = \frac{m}{n}\\
n^2(a+b)^2& = 4m^2ab\\
n^2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+2\right) &=4m^2.
\end{align*}
Let $\frac{a}{b}=t$, then you have a quadratic equation to solve
$$n^2t^2+(2n^2-4m^2)t+n^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply componendo &dividendo in ratio of AM/GM and then u will get root A +root B ka whole square on top and root a -root B ka whole square in bottom,then u can easily get ratio.i am new so I am not able to upload image to show u

Comment: But rohit singh i know that approach to solve this ques ...i wanna to solve using other method

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is too allusive : it doesn'r meet the standards of mathematical writing (see the other answers).

Comment: Then u can check others have also given there methods and I think all are correct

Comment: See Jean I told u I am a new user and don't know mathjax

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my unique solution to this problem. If AM and GM are in the ratio $m:n$, let $A=mk$ and $G=nk$.

This gives $a+b=2A$ and $ab= G^2$. Now create a quadratic equation whose roots are $a$ and $b$.
$$x^2-2Ax+G^2=0$$

Solve for $a$ and $b$ using the quadratic formula.